# Reusable functions in Firebase Cloud Functions

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

My problem is trying to define a local function in Firebase Cloud Functions. I would like my function to be global and reusable, but it seems to not export when I deploy using Firebase-CLI.

```
function mapEvents(data) {
    // Very long calculation
    ...
    return events
}

exports.importEvents = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    ...
    const mappedEvents = mapEvents(data);
    ...
})
```

This is the logged error I'm getting in the Firebase console when I run importEvents:

> TypeError: this.mapEvent is not a function
>       at module.exports.importEvents.functions.https.onRequest (/user_code/index.js:199:29)
>       at cloudFunction (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/providers/https.js:26:41)

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is here.  It seems like you're able to call mapEvents from importEvents.

Comment: My apologies, should've included the error message. Now edited the question.

Comment: That is really strange.  Is the function **mapEvents** in Index.js?  It should work fine.

Comment: On top of what JamWils said, could you switch from arrow function to `function`?

Comment: Did you found the fix?

Answer (score 4):

This might be late but helpful for someone else.

Since you are using ***arrow function*** on `exports.importEvents`

Update the mapEvents function to ***arrow function***

```
const mapEvents = (data) => {
    // Very long calculation
    ...
    return events
}
```

Hope this helps

You can read more about Arrow Functions here

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: Hi, can you explain why ?

Comment: did this work for you? did you figure out a solution?

Comment: @DJSjr Yes it worked. It was a long time ago.